# emacs delete-trailing-whitespace except current line

Tags: emacs, removing-whitespace

I recently added Emacs `(delete-trailing-whitespace)` function to my `'before-save-hook` for some programming modes, but I find it rather frustrating that it deletes whitespace from the line I am currently editing. Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem?

Comment: I must say I don't understand why you want to preserve trailing whitespace on the current line.

Comment: The justification: when I'm in the middle of editing a file, I save my document rather compulsively. If I start typing "print " and then save my buffer, the line shrinks to "print" and the cursor recedes, forcing me to type another space!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `delete-trailing-whitespace` respects narrowing, one solution is to narrow the buffer to the portion *before* the current line and call it, then narrow to the portion *after* the current line and call it again:

```
(defun delete-trailing-whitespace-except-current-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((begin (line-beginning-position))
        (end (line-end-position)))
    (save-excursion
      (when (< (point-min) begin)
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region (point-min) (1- begin))
          (delete-trailing-whitespace)))
      (when (> (point-max) end)
        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region (1+ end) (point-max))
          (delete-trailing-whitespace))))))
```

Put this function on your `before-save-hook` instead of `delete-trailing-whitespace`.

Answer (score 4):

This wrapper for `delete-trailing-whitespace` can be used to do what you want:

```
(defun delete-trailing-whitespace-except-current-line ()
  "do delete-trailing-whitespace, except preserve whitespace of current line"
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-line (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
        (backward (- (line-end-position) (point))))
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)
    (when (not (string-equal (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
                             current-line))
      (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
      (insert current-line)
      (backward-char backward))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and found out that [ws-butler](https://github.com/lewang/ws-butler) perfectly solves it.
There is a simple sample config code:

```
;; autoload ws-butler on file open
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'ws-butler-global-mode)
(setq require-final-newline t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply have a wrapper to make two calls to `delete-trailing-whitespace':

```el
(defun modi/delete-trailing-whitespace-buffer ()
  "Delete trailing whitespace in the whole buffer, except on the current line.
The current line exception is because we do want to remove any whitespace
on the current line on saving the file (`before-save-hook') while we are
in-between typing something.

Do not do anything if `do-not-delete-trailing-whitespace' is non-nil."
  (interactive)
  (when (not (bound-and-true-p do-not-delete-trailing-whitespace))
    (delete-trailing-whitespace (point-min) (line-beginning-position))
    (delete-trailing-whitespace (line-end-position) (point-max))))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'modi/delete-trailing-whitespace-buffer)
```